# Sudden increase in direct traffic after website redesign

Tags: 301-redirect, high-traffic

I recently redesigned my website and made 301 redirects from the old website's URLs to the new website's URLs. I've noticed a sudden increase in direct traffic. I'm not sure why this is happening. Can anyone explain why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you saying you want less traffic?

Comment: Of course, I want traffic but this sudden increase in direct traffic can be a sign of a problem.

Comment: Maybe it is a sign that you fixed a problem.

Comment: It may simply be that google re-indexed all the content on the new site and its evaluation of the content after re-indexing was higher than its evaluation of the content on the old site ... Google does not re-evaluate content at times when the content is being changed, this is to prevent SEO tweaking of content; So on a full evaluation, the content is better than what was being shown ... it was just not being shown while on the old site. Congratulations on the increase, its not a problem but not something to expect. ... you confirmed the non-re-evalutation algo.

Comment: Sounds like a win to me